# z-index and position relative

Tags: css, css-position

I have a modal, that is show/hide using JavaScript.

In the modal an image will be inserted using JavaScript. Also over the image a div element will exist that will simulate cropping (get the coordinates of the image).

I have a problem making the image to stay below the modal-crop.
modal-crop and the image need to be in the center of modal-area.

I can't use grid or flex because I need to support IE9.

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-area img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-crop {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-area">
    <div class="modal-crop"></div>
    #img will be inserted here using Javascript#
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't really show up anything. Consider adding a working snippet, that'd be helpful to further analyse the problem.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle and explicitly expose what is the problem and what you want to achieve? the snippet doesn't show anything

Comment: Can you ensure that your code snippet shows exactly what you're describing? Right now I'm only seeing a blank rendered test case.

Comment: Rahul, Lorenzo, Terry - please see the attached image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image need to be positionned absolutely like this :

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.modal-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-area img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-crop {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-area">
    <div class="modal-crop"></div>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image needs to be in modal-area but below modal crop - please see attached image

Comment: yes its below modal crop, you may change the opacity of modal-crop and you will notice it

Comment: ah sorry ! got it, check now !

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an understanding of what you want to achieve. And I also know that it can be a pain to overlap elements with absolute positioning in multiple layers (even more so when it comes to different browsers).

I recommend you to use a grid layout, which is quite easy to set up:

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-area">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
        <div class="modal-crop"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1050;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
outline: 0;
    }


.modal-area {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-items:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-area img {
    grid-row: 1/span 1;
    grid-column: 1/span 1;
    z-index:1;
}


.modal-crop  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  grid-row: 1/span 1;
  grid-column: 1/span 1;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Be aware though, that in this solution the "modal crop" needs to be set to width and and height of the image. But I used similar solutions in other situations and will not be hard to adjust it so that it works for any image sizes.

Have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9odLnh7r/

Comment: thanks, this is what I want to achieve(excepting modal will be centered), but I can't use grid or flex because I need to support IE10

Comment: I see, thats a valid point. It still might be doable since IE10 does support some older version of grid and flex but I would also think that it will get a bit unwieldy this way.

Answer (score 0):

The question is note very clear, but as far as I understand you need to add this css ruleset to your image:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
/*  display: none; */
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-area img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-crop {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 2;
}

.centerMe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-area">
    <div class="modal-crop"></div>
    <img class="centerMe" src="http://www.budgetstockphoto.com/bamers/stock_photo_spectrum.jpg"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image needs to be in modal-area but below modal crop - please see attached image